# $WP_Query: How to display excerpt on first post only

Tags: wp-query, loop, excerpt

Why does my `$featured_query` treat every post as the first? Following [Pieter's advice here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/188618/110886), and similar posts, using the built-in loop counter I've been unable to display the excerpt on first post only.

`front-page.php` has a featured projects section, calling a template part:

```
<section id="featured">

    <?php // Start custom loop
        $args = array( 
                'post_type' => 'project',
                'posts_per_page' => 5,
                );
        $featured_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

        while ( $featured_query->have_posts() ) : $featured_query->the_post(); 

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-archive', 'project' );

        endwhile; 
        wp_reset_postdata(); // Reset loop data
    ?>

</section>
```

`content-archive-project.php` looks like this:

```
<article class="project">

<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
    the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumbnail', 
        array( 'class' => 'featured' )); 
        } 
?>

    <header class="entry-header">

        <?php the_title( '<h2><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' ); ?>
        <p><?php
        $tagline  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'aj_post_tagline', true );
        echo esc_html( $tagline );
        ?></p>

    </header>

<?php if ( $featured_query->current_post == 0 ) { ?>

    <section class="entry-content">
           <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </section>

<?php } ?>

</article>
```

Comment: I only see one loop. Regardless, a "break" statement will usually end the loop.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your answer, RT… are you able to suggest a solution?  The code/loop above successfully displays the five most recent featured projects, on my homepage, each with their own unique excerpt.

Comment: I'm not sure that the post count comes through onto template parts.  Can you try echoing the post count and seeing if it is actually providing a count?

Comment: @rudtek, you're right, echoing the post count displays "1" next to each. Strange, they each have their own excerpts though... is there any way to resolve my original issue? Displaying first excerpt only? Seems very inefficient to have to duplicate code from a working file (content-archive-project.php) to do this. Defeats the point of template parts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull it out of the content-part.  That would be the easiest.

```
<section id="featured">

    <?php // Start custom loop
        $args = array( 
                'post_type' => 'project',
                'posts_per_page' => 5,
                );
        $featured_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

        while ( $featured_query->have_posts() ) : $featured_query->the_post(); 
    ?>
    <article class="project">

    <?php 
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
            the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumbnail', 
            array( 'class' => 'featured' )); 
        } 
    ?>

    <header class="entry-header">

        <?php the_title( '<h2><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' ); ?>
        <p><?php
        $tagline  = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'aj_post_tagline', true );
        echo esc_html( $tagline );
        ?></p>

    </header>

    <?php if ( $featured_query->current_post == 0 ) { ?>

        <section class="entry-content">
           <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </section>

    <?php } ?>

    </article>

    <php
        endwhile; 
        wp_reset_postdata(); // Reset loop data
    ?>

</section>
```

Another option would be to try this line:

```
include( locate_template( 'template-parts/content-archive-project.php', false, false ) );
```

instead of :

```
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-archive', 'project' );
```

but you should test that as I didn't.